# iDraw application automatically changed name to Graphic

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, auto-updates

So iDraw was recently acquired by Autodesk (name has changed to Graphic) and even though I didn't download an update, or have autoupdate enabled, it automatically changed the application's name. I spent quite sometime trying to figure out where my iDraw application had gone.

Anyone knows how this is something they can just update without autoupdate being enabled? Is my computer constantly checking in with Appstore for software licensing verification? (even that wouldn't necessarily mean downloading an update)

---

***RELATED TO ANSWER:***
**Example of the preferences thanks to SaxDaddy. It seems that it was considered a "data file" update since the application was acquired by another company and had changed names**

[image: Example of the preferences thanks to SaxDaddy.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X has the ability to auto update app store apps. That may be the case for you.

To disable this behavior,

1. From the Apple menu, click System Preferences.
2. Go to the App Store panel. You will see options to "Install OS X Updates".
3. Uncheck "Install App updates" to disable these updates

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Quite a few options to choose from. Seems like I had some of them partially enabled, including downloading updates and then check to see if I want to install them, which sometimes might occupy unnecessary space.